# Is there a way to get an event when a device twins reported properties change?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

Looking through the apis for DeviceClient, ServiceClient, and RegistryManager it doesn't look like there is any obvious way to get an event/callback when the reported properties for a device have changed. Therefore it seems like something consuming the IoTHub information wouldn't have any idea properties have changed without constantly polling. That seems rather inefficient and error prone. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The device twins has built-in an event driven notification model when the changes on the tags and properties are published via the Azure IoT Hub Routes path to the custom endpoints. See more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins).

The following screen snippet shows an example of the Azure IoT Hub Routes for *TwinChangeEvents* notifications:

[image]